# Update Claims without logging out

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

I have this code on `EnableAuthenticator` so after user verified the code I want to update the claim.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> EnableAuthenticator(EnableAuthenticatorViewModel enableAuthenticatorViewModel)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        await LoadSharedKeyAndQrCodeUriAsync(user, enableAuthenticatorViewModel);
        return View(enableAuthenticatorViewModel);
    }

    // Strip spaces and hyphens
    var verificationCode = enableAuthenticatorViewModel.Input.Code.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("-", string.Empty);

    var is2faTokenValid = await _userManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(
        user, _userManager.Options.Tokens.AuthenticatorTokenProvider, verificationCode);

     if (!is2faTokenValid)
     {
         ModelState.AddModelError("Input.Code", "Verification code is invalid.");
         await LoadSharedKeyAndQrCodeUriAsync(user, enableAuthenticatorViewModel);
         return View(enableAuthenticatorViewModel);
      }

      await _userManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user, true);
      var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);

      TempData["StatusMessage"] = "Your authenticator app has been verified.";

      // update the claim
      // The below code is not updating the claims
      var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)this.User.Identity;

      var amrClaimType = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "amr").Single();
      identity.RemoveClaim(amrClaimType);

      identity.AddClaim(new Claim("amr", "mfa"));

      return RedirectToAction("Users","Admin");

      //if (await _userManager.CountRecoveryCodesAsync(user) == 0)
      //{
      //    var recoveryCodes = await _userManager.GenerateNewTwoFactorRecoveryCodesAsync(user, 10);
      //    TempData["RecoveryCodes"] = recoveryCodes.ToArray();
      //    return RedirectToAction("ShowRecoveryCodes");
      //}
      //else
      //{
      //    return RedirectToAction("TwoFactorAuthentication");
      //}
}
```

After setting up authenticator I want to update the claims value from pwd to mfa but the above code is not working. I am using ASP.NET Core 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identity is based on Cookie Authentication,when you redirect to another Page,it would read ClaimsPrinciple from cookie and assign it to httpcontext,so if you want to get the relaced claim in the handler of another page,you have to reset the cookie:

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)this.User.Identity;
            var amrClaimType = identity?.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "amr").FirstOrDefault();

            identity.RemoveClaim(amrClaimType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("amr", "mfa"));
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(identity)
            );
```